# Looping through fields in awk

Tags: awk, sed

Suppose I have the following three lines in a text file:

```
I have a dog 
The dog is goood
The cat runs well
```

Now I need to go through the file. And print the lines where the word `dog` occurs along with the field no in which it occurs. I need to accomplish this through `awk`.

Is there any way by which while processing a line I can sequentially increase the field number, something like the following:

```
more abc.txt | awk ' j = $NF for (i =1 ; i<= j ; ++i) if ( $N$i == "dog") n= $N0" "$i '
```

How to loop through the fields of a line in awk?

Comment: Why do you need to accomplish this through `awk` specifically (and you tagged the question `awk` and `sed`)?

Answer (score 33):

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if($i=="dog") print $0,i}}' file
```

Output:

```
I have a dog 4
The dog is goood 2
```

I assume that each line contains the searched string only once.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution:**

```
awk '/dog/ {for(i=NF;i>=1;i--) {if($i~/dog/) {$0=i":"$0}} print}' file
```

**Input file:**

```
I have a dog 
The dog is a good doggie
The cat runs well
```

**Output:**

```
4:I have a dog 
2:6:The dog is a good doggie
```

**Features:**

- First checks whether the line contains the desired text before cycling through the fields (although I don't think this provides much of a speedup)
- Not only finds fields that are identical to the desired text, but also fields that *contain* it
- Prints the field number of *all* fields in the line that match the desired text

Answer (score 3):

`$NF` holds last field value, `i` is a number and `$i` refers to a field value on that number. `$N$i` means field number `0` (which is whole line, since `N` isn't initialized) concatenated to value of field number `i`. You are doing almost every thing wrong. Try:

```
more abc.txt | awk '{for (i =1; i<=NF ; i++) if ($i == "dog") print $0 i}'
```